# How to write is_home function Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure how to write the `is_home()` included in this statement:

```
if (function_exists('ditty_news_ticker')){
  ditty_news_ticker(47);
}
```

I've tried a few different ways but I keep breaking it. I'm sure there is a pretty simply solution, but I am moderately new to php.

Comment: Try this `if (is_home() && function_exists('ditty_news_ticker')){ditty_news_ticker(47);}`

Comment: Actually, is_home() didn't seem to work anyway, so I went with is_front_page() instead - but the && what what I needed - thanks!!!

Comment: In wp `is_home()` means blog home NOT site front page. Which page you really want? `front page` or `blog home`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (function_exists('ditty_news_ticker') && is_home()){ ditty_news_ticker(47); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out:

```
if (function_exists('ditty_news_ticker') && is_front_page() ){ditty_news_ticker(47);}
```